# adding nested field in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using **Angular 6** and have written API in **Django**.

I have a **Profile** model serialized under **User** model.

Using **Postman** I'm able to save records to **Profile** like

```
# JSON
{
    'name': 'John',
    'profile': {
       'about': 'About me string'
    }
}

# or form field
name = 'John'
profile.about = 'About me string'
```

Now, In Angular application, I am trying to send data in the same format described above to the endpoint. For that, the formGroup is like

```
this.aboutForm = this.fb.group({
  profile: this.fb.group({
    about: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
    ])
  })
});
```

And when the HTML form be like

```
<form [formGroup]="aboutForm" (submit)="submit()" #form="ngForm">
    <textarea formControlName="profile.about"></textarea>
</form>
```

But this is giving error as

```
error service Error: "Cannot find control with name: 'profile.about'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `formGroupName` instead of `formControlName` for nested controls.

Enclose the `textarea` inside  div with `formGroupName=profile` and then use the `formControlName=about` for your `texarea`

Comment: what should be the value of `formGroupName`?